# Truncating a Table Before Loading in an AWS Glue Notebook

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I have found that it is possible to do it, but with redshift how could it be done differently with spark or the glue catalog ?

I'm facing an issue while trying to truncate a table before loading it using an AWS Glue notebook.

Answer (score 0):

I am sharing the code snippet to truncate a table before loading it in an AWS Glue notebook. This code helps to ensure that the target table is cleared of any existing data before new data is loaded.

```
sdf =spark.sql(sql)

conf = glueContext.extract_jdbc_conf("conn-dlh-datos-fed")
(sdf.write 
.mode('overwrite') 
.format("jdbc")  
.option("url", conf['url']) 
.option("connschema", "<db>")  
.option("user", conf['user'])
.option("dbtable", "<schema>.<table>") 
.option('truncate','true') 
.option("password", conf['password']) 
.save()
)
```

or alternatively:

```
sdf=spark.sql(sql)

conf = glueContext.extract_jdbc_conf("conn-dlh-datos-fed")

(sdf.write 
.mode('overwrite') 
.format("jdbc") 
.option("url", f"{conf['url']}/{conf['url'].split('//')[1].split('.')[0]}?user={conf['user']}&password={conf['password']}&ReadOnly=false") 
.option("dbtable", "<schema>.<table>") 
.option('truncate','true') 
.save()
)
```

Note that db name i get spliting the url conf

The complete url is : `'jdbc:postgresql://<db>.xxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/<db>?user=<user>&password=<pass>&ReadOnly=false'`

Original solution can be find this  :[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67695928/emr-pyspark-write-to-redshift-java-sql-sqlexception-amazon500310-invalid-o)